# How to Import jasny-bootstrap to Angular 4?

Tags: angular, jasny-bootstrap

Jasny Bootstrap:

https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap

Installed: `npm install jasny-bootstrap --save`

Imported in `app/app.module.ts` or `main.ts`

`import * as jasny from 'jasny-bootstrap';`

I got this error:

`ERROR in /Users/Roller/Working/Angular4/src/app/app.module.ts (11,24): Cannot find module 'jasny-bootstrap'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jasny-bootstrap` is not Angular module, it's just javascript library. If you use angular-cli, you can include this script in your `.angular-cli.json` file. That's how you do this:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

and the same thing with css files:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```